# How to align a h4 and img element within a navbar?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

A homework assignment asks to create a nav/navbar area that includes a div, with an image and a heading, that comes before the collapsible button.

I want the image and heading to be aligned side by side, and not disappear when the port/screen size changes.

```
    <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-secondary">
        <div>
                <img src="steve_headset_sm5.jpg" class="navbar-brand" alt="steve_with_headset"> 
<h4>My Website 3.0</h4>
        </div>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarmenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarmenu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Main Content</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Python</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">SQL</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">JavaScript</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">PHP</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

The issue, as seen in the code below, is that the image and heading stack in top of each other. Could anyone point me as to what I am doing wrong/should do?

Comment: Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=AxcC1loyF8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `inline-block`, but I would recommend learning about flexbox. Is this what you're looking for?

```css
.nav-inline {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
.nav-inline h4 {
margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
 
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-secondary">
        <div class="nav-inline">
                <img src="steve_headset_sm5.jpg" class="navbar-brand" alt="steve_with_headset"> 
<h4>My Website 3.0</h4>
        </div>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarmenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarmenu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Main Content</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Python</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">SQL</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">JavaScript</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">PHP</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Yes, just like this. Seems like I am missing some basic html/css on how to align elements within a div. Thank you

Comment: When it comes to layout and alignment, flexbox makes it very easy.